# best algorithm for face detection and pose estimation

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, face-detection

I am looking for algorithms/publications on face detection. There are plenty in the web. But my scenario is somewhat specialized. I want to detect faces accurately in images taken by wearable devices (e.g. narrative clips), so there will be motion blur, and image quality will not be that good. I want to detect faces that are within 15 feet of the camera accurately. Next goal is to estimate the pose, primarily to find out if the person is looking toward the camera ( or better looking at the camera owner).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

My go to for this would either be a deep-learning framework using convolutional layers for pixel classification, or K-means/ K-Nearest Neighbour algorithm.

This does depend on your data, however. From your post I am assuming that your data isn't labelled? meaning you are unable to feed in the 'truth' to the algorithm for classification.

you could perhaps use a CNN (convolutional neural network) for pixel classification (image segmentation) which should identify the location of a person. given this, perhaps you could run a 'local' CNN i a region close to the face identified to classify the region the body is located in as a certain pose.

This would probably be my first take on the problem but would depend on the exact structure of your data, and the structure of your labels (if you have any).

I have to say it does sound like a fun project!

Answer (score 0):

I found OpenCV's [Haar Cascades for Face Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0) pretty accurate and robust for motion blur and "live" face recognition.

I'm saying that because I used them for implementing an Eye-Tracker in C++ with a laptop webcam (whose resolution was not excellent and motion blur was naturally always present).

They work in multiresolution and are therefore able to detect faces of any size, but you can easily tune them for your distance of interest.

They might not be your final optimal solution, but since they are already implemented and come with the OpenCV package, they could constitute a good starting point.